# VBA 2015 find variable using part of his name

Tags: vba, variables, search, find

I have:

```
Dim some340id, some341id, someCDFid, someARCid, some8FGid etc... as String
```

Need to find:

```
Dim idtofind as String = "ARC"
```

something like:

```
Dim Found As String = some{idtofind}id
```

How to write code for this?

Comment: This is not VBA code, nor is there any such thing as VBA 2015. This is probably VB.NET. You should tag your question correctly, then the right people will see it. The .NET Framework has possibilities not available in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although VB is an interpreter, I don't know if you can do this. But what you can do is use an array and index that with a meaningful `Const` name, for example:

```
Private Const i340id As Integer = 0
Private Const i341id As Integer = 1
...
Private Const iMAXid As Integer = 99

Dim some(iMAXid) As String

MsgBox "String is " & some(i341id)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Paul, not working ("String is " empty), but i try to mod Your solution and now it's working. Much thank You.

```
Public Const incoming340id As Integer = 0
    Public Const incoming341id As Integer = 1
    Public Const incomingMAXid As Integer = 99

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim some As String = 341

    MsgBox("String is " & "incoming" & some.ToString & "id")
End Sub
```

Now how to result change to working variable?

```
Dim somethingNew as String = "incoming" & some.ToString & "id"
```

I have somethingNew, and want to worki it like variable incoming341id

```
incoming341id = otherResult.Text
```

but now i have "somethingNew"...

Comment: Seems you didn't get the idea: you CANNOT get the name of a variable programmatically. Instead, use an array that repesent the variables and use indexes that are constats with meaningful names. And `Dim some As String = 341` won't work as you cannot initialize a variable in VB, only constants. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336006/reference-variable-name-in-excel-vba